# Minimum number puzzle!

Tags: wordplay, english

What is the minimum number of letters required to satisfy all the following clues?

> "especially bad"
>  "earth's counterpart"
>  "flows one-way,
>   strictly"
>  "release as outward flow"
>   
>   "being this is being a jerk"
>  "locks of one particular feline"
>  "source of vegan's
>   disgust"
>  "mild and obsequious "
>   
>   "a currency"
>  "a monster's hideout"
>  "especially nasty"
>  "to
>   cover"
>   
>   "amorous partner"
>  "sports group"
>  "tiny, tiny bug"
>  "a listing"
>   
>   "habitually presents alternate facts"
>  "a transport system"
>   "an artificial and meaningless convention, as per Juliet"
>  "so be
>   it"

---

END

Comment: crossword-clues tag? not sure tho... or enigmatic-puzzle?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton they seem well suited too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

> 9 (a,e,i,m,n,t,l,r,v)

is the appropriate number.

These seem to come in

> groups of four-letter words that are anagrams of each other:

"especially bad"

> evil

"earth's counterpart"

> live (in electrical wiring)

"flows one-way, strictly"

> time

"release as outward flow"

> emit

"being this is being a jerk"

> mean

"locks of one particular feline"

> mane

"source of vegan's disgust"

> meat

"mild and obsequious "

> tame

"a currency"

> rial

"a monster's hideout"

> lair

"especially nasty"

> vile

"to cover"

> veil

"amorous partner"

> mate

"sports group"

> team

"tiny, tiny bug"

> mite

"a listing"

> item

"habitually presents alternate facts"

> liar

"a transport system"

> rail

"an artificial and meaningless convention, as per Juliet"

> name

"so be it"

> amen

Comment: too damn quick :)